# PHP Generate preview of Microsoft formats

Tags: php, image, preview, doc

I've made in PHP (using GD and Imagick) a image preview generator for jpg, gif, png, bmp, txt, csv and pdf files, but I'm having troubles on finding a solution for Microsoft types: doc, xls and ppt.

Anyone has some ideas on how to generate them?

Comment: I usually just pop up a large copy of the word/excel/powerpoint icons. There's no way to render previews of the formats without involving a full office suite to open/parse the files.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/books/docs/viewer/developers_guide.html
http://blogs.digitss.com/tools-plugins-extenstion/use-google-docs-viewer-for-document-viewing-within-browser/

I think that these formats are proprieraty.. Check google viewer or search for another solution..